# Merge Documents and Relink Documents view

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, list-view, view

I don't know how this happened, but when I click the drop down to see the view for my library, there is now an additional "Merge Documents" and "Relink Documents" view.

[image]

Where does this come from and how can I get rid of it? I cannot recreate this nor remove it.

This is SharePoint 2013 Enterprise edition.

Answer (score 2):

These are available in Form libraries and users with "edit" permissions will see them.  If users don't need to edit items, grant them "read-only" permission instead and those should go away.

If you are not hosting InfoPath forms than you don't need a form library.  Use a document library/app instead and move your documents there - you should not see those links there.

**Edit**

It turns out you can remove those views.  I have validated this works.  After you have removed the "form" content type, you can open the list in SharePoint Designer (use the all files view), under the forms folder you will see

```
Combine.aspx
Repair.aspx
```

Remove those and your views will be gone from your dropdown as well.

***Warning***
They will be gone forever - even if you add the forms content type back at a later date.  You would have to manually copy over those pages from a working library to get those views back.

Comment: This library was created using the document library app. Something happend since to change it.

Comment: check your content types - were any InfoPath forms added?

Comment: There weren't any Infopath form content types in this library. I created another library with the exact same content types and settings, but still didn't see those links on the view drop down. What I just did was to add the Form content type, and now I see the Merge Documents and Relink Documents views. I removed the form content type, and those links are still there! Seems buggy to me. Someone must have added that content type on accident, and now we're left with those annoying links. There must be some way to remove them right?

Comment: See edit - you can remove those.

Comment: The views can also be deleted by using the object model (e.g. with Powershell): $list.Views.Delete($mergeView.ID)